# Continuous functions on locally compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Show every closed Ideal in $C_0(X)$ for a locally compact Hausdorff space X is of the form $K_F=\{f\in C_0(X)\colon f\lvert_F \equiv 0\}$ for some closed subspace $F\subseteq X$.

Here is what I have so far:

Let $I$ be a closed ideal.

I tried to use the Gelfand Transform.

Consider the evaluation map $ev_x: C_0(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $ev_x(f)= f(x)$ for all $x \in F$. Then we have $Ker (ev_x)= K_F$

From here, I'm pretty much lost what to do to get the result desired.

Also, I thought about using Urysohn's Lemma here: [https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/1-05-top-loc-comp.pdf](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Enagy/real-an/1-05-top-loc-comp.pdf) . But still didn't anywhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about the Gelfand transform ? How does the ideal fact follow from that? Please make it more explicit?

Comment: You can also use that $f \in C_0(X)$ has a unique extension to $C(\alpha X)$ where $\alpha X$ is the one-point compactification of $X$, and then apply theory on ideals there.

Comment: Consider what $F$ should be, given $I$. It should be a subset of $Z_f$ for all $f\in I$. Try to show that $\{Z_f:f\in I\}$ has nonempty intersection.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma How would you continue this attempt?

Let $\widehat{X}= X \cup \{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $X$. Given $f \in C_0(X)$, let $\hat{f}$ be the extension of $f$ on $\widehat{X}$ with $\hat{f}(\infty) = 0$. Then $\hat{f} \in C(\widehat{X})$, since $f$ vanishes on infinity. 

Let $I$ be a closed ideal in $C_0(X)$ and consider $\widehat{I}= \{\hat{f}: f \in I\}$. Check that $\hat{I}$ is an ideal in $C(X)$. It is well known that there exists $z \in \widehat{X}$ such that
$$\widehat{I}= \{g \in C(\widehat{X})\mid g(z) = 0\}.$$

Comment: If $z \in X$, then $I = K_{\{z\}}$. But what if $z = \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a closed ideal $I\trianglelefteq  C_0(X)$, let
$$
  F=\{x\in X: f(x)=0,  \text{ for all } f\in I\},
  $$
and let us prove that $I=K_F$.

The inclusion  $I\subseteq K_F$ holds for a pretty elementary reason (which nevertheless sounds a bit like a tongue-twister):
every function in $I$ vanishes on any point where all functions in $I$ vanish.

The hard part is to prove the reverse inclusion $K_F\subseteq I$.   For this  pick  $f\in  K_f$.  Fixing  $\varepsilon >0$, recall that the set
$$
  C=\{x\in  X: |f(x)|\geq  \varepsilon \}
  $$
is compact.

Given  $x$ in $C$, we have that $f(x)$ is nonzero, so clearly $x$ is not in $F$.  Consequently not all functions in $I$
vanish at $x$, and hence we may choose  some element $a_x\in  I$, such that $a_x(x)\neq 0$.  The set
$$
  U_x=\{y\in X: a_x(y)\neq 0\}
  $$
is then an open neighborhood of $x$, and hence $\{U_x\}_{x\in C}$ is an open cover of $C$.  By compactness we may pick a
finite subcover $\{U_{x_1},U_{x_2},\ldots ,U_{x_n}\}$.  Next observe that
$$
  g:= \sum_{i=1}^n\overline {a}_{x_i}a_{x_i}
  $$
lies in $I$, and does not vanish on any point of $C$.

There are multiple endings for this story,  and perpahs the slickest way is as follows:  besides an ideal,  $I$ is a
C*-algebra and $g$ is a non-negative element in $I$, so $g^{1/p}$ lies in $I$  for every positive integer $p$.
Moreover the sequence $\{g^{1/p}\}_{p\in {\mathbb N}}$ converges uniformly to 1 on $C$.  It is also easy to see that
$$
  \|g^{1/p}\| =   \|g\|^{1/p} \leq  2,
  $$
for large enough $p$.
Therefore we may find  $p$ such that
$$
  |f(x)-g(x)^{1/p}f(x)| < \varepsilon , \quad\forall x\in  C,
  $$
and
$$
  |f(x)-g(x)^{1/p}f(x)|  \leq  \big (1+|g(x)^{1/p}|\big ) |f(x)|\leq  (1+2)\varepsilon ,
  $$
for every  $x\in  X\setminus C$.
Consequently $\|f - g^{1/p}f\|\leq  3\varepsilon $, so we deduce that $f$ lies in the closure of $I$, and hence also in $I$
because $I$ is closed.

---

**EDIT**. Here is another approach,  assuming we already know the answer in case $X$ is compact.

Assuming that $X$ is not compact, let $\hat X=X\cup \{\infty \}$
be the one-point compactification of $X$, and let
$$
  f\in C_0(X)\mapsto \hat f\in  C(\hat X)
  $$
be the natural identification.  One may then prove that $\hat I$ is a closed ideal in $C(\hat X)$, and hence, by the
compact case,
$$
  \hat I=\{g\in C(\hat X) : g|_G=0\},
  $$
where $G$ is a closed subset of $\hat X$.

Notice that necessarily $\infty \in G$, since otherwise one could use Urysohn to
produce some $g\in C(\hat X)$, vanishing on $G$, with $g(\infty )\neq 0$, but this would imply that $g$ lies in
$\hat I\setminus C_0(X)$, which is impossible.

Setting $F=G\cap X$, we have  that $F$ is a closed subset of $X$.   So, upon identifying $C_0(X)$ as the subalgebra of $C(\hat
X)$ formed by the functions vanishing at $\infty $, we have:
$$
  \hat I=\{g\in C(\hat X) : g|_G=0\} = $$$$ =
  \{g\in C(\hat X) : g|_F=0\} \cap  \{g\in C(\hat X) : g(\infty )=0\} = $$$$ =
  \{g\in C(\hat X) : g|_F=0\} \cap  C_0(X) = $$$$ =
  \{g\in C_0(X) : g|_F=0\} = K_F.
  $$

Comment: Thanks. Do you perhaps know an approach that builds further on the one-point compactification idea in the comments?

Comment: @QuantumSpace, I think the statement after "It is well known ...", in your comment, only holds for maximal ideals.

Comment: Obviously you are right. Any idea then how one can use the hint of Henno Brandsma in the comments?

Comment: @QuantumSpace,  if $I$ is a closed  ideal in $C_0(X)$,  which is an ideal in $C(\alpha X)$, then $I$ is an ideal in $C(\alpha X)$ (because closed
ideals in C*-algebras  are idempotent).  Therefore, assuming you know the answer for compact spaces,  you may apply it
to  answer the question.  However it seems to me that the OP is not assuming the result known in the compact case.

Comment: Yes, but I put a bounty on this question because I want to see an answer that uses one-point compactification and because I didn't want to start a new question. You can assume the answer is known in the compact case.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: Oh!  Now I see!  Give me a minute and I will add an alternative answer using this method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruy!